# Do deployments of multiple cubesats generally obey proposed guidelines such as 20 seconds or more between deployments at 5 m/s or faster?

Tags: cubesat, tracking, payload-deployment, regulatory, smallsat

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/40777/12102) to *What can be done in future mass-cubesat deploys to make them “less irksome” to orbital space debris experts?* links to [Space Traffic Safety: A New Self-Governance Approach for the Smallsat Community SSC17-XI-02](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d5e9/173f06bea1b18ae8dc6a6cf1ba17e2d53464.pdf) and includes the following:

> A number of potential technical solutions exist to help improve the tracking accuracy for small satellites. For instance, in 2006 a set of post-launch guidelines were suggested by members of the Space Analysis branch of the Air Force Space Command that would significantly improve the tracking ease during the initial object identification period. These included:
>
> 1. Coordinate launch trajectory and initial orbit information.
> 2. For multi-satellite launches information regarding deployment sequence, separation timing, and object shape and size is extremely beneficial.
> 3. Sequential satellite deployments should be separated by at least 20 seconds.
> 4. Separation velocity between the satellite and the launch vehicle should be at least 5 meters/second or more.
> 5. Report problems identified in two-line element sets.
> 6. Notify tracking authorities if assistance is desired with issues regarding satellite anomalies and/or loss of contact.<sup>10</sup>
>
> <sup>10</sup>DeVere, G. and J. C. Randolph. “How to Improve Small Satellite Missions in Two Easy Steps: Adopting Space Debris Mitigation Guidelines and Improving Space Surveillance Network Tracking Support”. Proceedings of the 20th Annual AIAA/USU Conference on Small Satellites, 2006.

**Question:** Do multiple cubesat deployments generally obey these proposed guidelines, including 20 seconds or more between deployments at 5 m/s or faster?

---

**Problems Assigning IDs for multi-satellite deployments:**

- [It's been over two weeks now, will the real Humanity Star please stand up?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24656/12102)
- [ISRO's PSLV-C37 with 104 satellites - after 56 hours only six TLEs, which factor is greatest challenge?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20191/12102)

**Other Problems keeping track of satellites:**

- [How (the heck) are military satellites with (apparently) classified TLEs still showing up on sat map websites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18300/12102)
- [Has NORAD ever experienced a catastrophic event and "lost track of" a bunch of objects?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26600/12102)
- [Are SpaceBEEs actually hard to track?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25978/12102)